# django forms passing parameters

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a dynamic form and I get an error with the post method because the parameter "waysNumber". The problem is in de line "formulari = WayForm(request.POST, request.FILES)", in the post method. It executes the function init() from the WayForm and now there is no parameter named waysNumber. Which is the correct way of passing this parameter? Here is my code:

forms.py:

```
class WayForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):         
        waysNumber = kwargs.pop("waysNumber")
        super(WayForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        CHOICES = (('1','Pista',),('2','Corriol',))            
        for i in range(waysNumber):
            self.fields["Descripcio"+str(i)]= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(),label="Descripcio"+str(i))
            self.fields["Tipus"+str(i)] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES, label="Tipus de camí"+str(i))
```

views.py:

```
def acoplar_track(request, track_id):    

    if request.method=='GET':
        track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=track_id) # obte el track i la zona corresponent al track   

        newWays_l = x.getTrackWays() # obte les ids dels nous camins que s'afegiran

        formulari = WayForm(waysNumber = len(newWays_l))                       
        return render(request,'principal/wayForm.html')

    else:
        formulari = WayForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formulari.is_valid():   
            ...                       
            return render_to_response('principal/inici.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not persisting the value across requests. Once you do a post, your parameter is not present on the `WayForm` instance. To get around this, you can initialize your form like so:

```
def acoplar_track(request, track_id):
    newWays_l = x.getTrackWays()
    formulari = WayForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
        waysNumber = len(newWays_l))

    if request.method=='GET':
        track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=track_id)
        return render(request,'principal/wayForm.html')
    else:
        if formulari.is_valid():      
            return render_to_response('principal/inici.html',
                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```